# Lisp, a couple of questions about lists and recursion

Tags: list, function, recursion, lisp

sorry to overflow with so many questions.

I have the following:

```
(defun recursive-function (string) "returns list of strings"
;I am trying to return flat list
; create list L
(append (mapcar 'recursive-function L)))
```

But since recursive-function returns a list, I end up with a list of a list of a list..., whereas I want just a flat list.

What is the proper way for me to implement recursion on functions which take a scalar and return a list of scalars?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can combine *reduce* and *append* to flatten the list before returning it.

Example:

```
(reduce 'append '((1) (2) (3)))
```

Output:

```
(1 2 3)
```

In your case this might work:

```
(reduce 'append (mapcar 'recursive-function L))
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive you are looking for [mapcan](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_mapc_.htm):

> [...] mapcan and mapcon are like mapcar and
>   maplist respectively, except that the
>   results of applying function are
>   combined into a list by the use of
>   nconc rather than list. [...]

```
(defun recursive-function (string) "returns list of strings"
   ;I am trying to return flat list
   ; create list L
   (mapcan 'recursive-function L))
```